# Symfony Error : Cannot use 'parent' in a class with no parent using class UserRepository extends ServiceEntityRepository

Tags: symfony, symfony6

I am encountering some errors in my Symfony project while trying to create an entity :

here's my code :
`user.php` :

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\UserRepository;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=UserRepository::class)
 */

 class User
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id = null;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $username = null;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $email = null;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $password = null;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $First_name = null;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $Last_name = null;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $address = null;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $phone_number = null;

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getUsername(): ?string
    {
        return $this->username;
    }

    public function setUsername(string $username): static
    {
        $this->username = $username;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getEmail(): ?string
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

    public function setEmail(string $email): static
    {
        $this->email = $email;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getPassword(): ?string
    {
        return $this->password;
    }

    public function setPassword(string $password): static
    {
        $this->password = $password;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getFirstName(): ?string
    {
        return $this->First_name;
    }

    public function setFirstName(string $First_name): static
    {
        $this->First_name = $First_name;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getLastName(): ?string
    {
        return $this->Last_name;
    }

    public function setLastName(string $Last_name): static
    {
        $this->Last_name = $Last_name;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getAddress(): ?string
    {
        return $this->address;
    }

    public function setAddress(string $address): static
    {
        $this->address = $address;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getPhoneNumber(): ?string
    {
        return $this->phone_number;
    }

    public function setPhoneNumber(string $phone_number): static
    {
        $this->phone_number = $phone_number;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

and here's my `userRepository.php` :

```
<?php

namespace App\Repository;

use App\Entity\User;
use Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Repository\ServiceEntityRepository;
use Doctrine\Persistence\ManagerRegistry;

/**
 * @extends ServiceEntityRepository<User>
 *
 * @method User|null find($id, $lockMode = null, $lockVersion = null)
 * @method User|null findOneBy(array $criteria, array $orderBy = null)
 * @method User[]    findAll()
 * @method User[]    findBy(array $criteria, array $orderBy = null, $limit = null, $offset = null)
 */
class UserRepository extends ServiceEntityRepository
{
    public function __construct(ManagerRegistry $registry)
    {
        parent::__construct($registry, User::class);
    }
}
```

And basically I am encountering errors in :

`class UserRepository extends ServiceEntityRepository`
Error : Undefined type 'Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Repository\ServiceEntityRepository.

`public function __construct(ManagerRegistry $registry)`
Error : Undefined type 'Doctrine\Persistence\ManagerRegistry.

`parent::__construct($registry, User::class);`
Error : Cannot use 'parent' in a class with no parent.

Comment: The fact that your entity is using annotations and not attributes in a Symfony 6 app is a bit suspicious.  Are you sure you have the doctrine bundle installed and didn't just copy your entity/repository from another project?

Comment: At first I was using attributes but it kept showing me error of undefined doctrine\ORM... then when i switched to annotations, it worked!